# How to access last element of nested ArrayList Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, nested

How do I access the last element in "lines" in the last element of "fractions" given the following code?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tube {

    // Make Tube a singleton class
    private static Tube instance = new Tube();
    private Tube() { }
    public static synchronized Tube getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public ArrayList<Fraction> fractions = new ArrayList<Fraction>();
}

class Fraction {
    public ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
}

public class Line {
    public Point start;
    public Point end;

    public Line(Point from, Point to) {
        start = from;
        end = to;
    }
}
```

Accessing the last element in "fractions" is easy:

```
Tube tube = Tube.getInstance();
Fraction fraction = tube.fractions.get(tube.fractions.size() - 1);
```

But how do I access the last element in "lines" in the last element of "fractions"?

```
Fraction fraction = tube.fractions.get(tube.fractions.size() - 1).lines.get(tube.fractions.get(tube.fractions.size - 1)... // and you get an evil spiral
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the same with lines list:

```
Tube tube = Tube.getInstance();
List<Line> lastFractionLines = tube.fractions.get(tube.fractions.size() - 1).lines;
Line lastLine = lastFractionLines.get(lastFractionLines.size() - 1);
```

Also try to make your fields private and use getters.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you @alaster

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while writing this post and thought I'd share my knowledge.

I do not think this can be done in one line like I first tried, but please do correct me if I'm wrong. First create a Fraction object containing the last element of "fractions". Then use this object to access the last element of "lines".

```
Tube tube = Tube.getInstance();
Fraction fraction = tube.fractions.get(tube.fractions.size() - 1);
Line line = fraction.lines.get(tube.fractions.size() - 1);
```

And there you have it!